# Who is Völsung's mother?

Tags: norse, volsunga

Völsung's mother, despite giving birth to the clan's namesake in a [rather bizarre manner](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/2216/57), is never named in the Völsunga saga.

Is her name mentioned anywhere else in the Völsung cycle? Do we know anything about her, other than being Rerir's wife and Völsung's mother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

Outside of the brief description of her, she is never given a name.